# How to solve this array to string conversion error

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have magento with magebridge to enter the site from Joomla. Magebridge.php is causing this error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in mysite/magebridge.php on line 54
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in mysite/magebridge.php on line 55

```
// Determine the Mage::app() arguments from the bridge
$app_value = (string) $magebridge->getMeta('app_value');
$app_type = (string) $magebridge->getMeta('app_type');

// Doublecheck certain values
if($app_type == 'website' && $app_value != 'admin') $app_value = (int)$app_value;
if($app_value == 'admin') $app_type = null;`
```

How can I solve this? Anyone an idea to help me forward? Thanks!

Comment: Check what `$magebridge->getMeta('app_value')` returns. I suppose it is array.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I am pretty new to this, so I am not sure how to check that exactly?

Comment: `print_r`, `var_dump`, google.

Answer (score 0):

You could join all items in your array with commas:

```
if(is_array($magebridge->getMeta('app_value'))) {
    $app_value = implode(',', $magebridge->getMeta('app_value'));
}
```

Or convert them to JSON:

```
$app_value = json_encode($magebridge->getMeta('app_value'));
```